# Conflicting versions of ASP.NET Web Pages detected version issue

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

i have .net framework 4.0 and mvc Version=3.0.0.0 there was error of conflicting of framework and mvc version.Then i execute this command
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 4.0.20710.0
but again its throwing same error 
"Conflicting versions of ASP.NET Web Pages detected: specified version is "1.0.0.0", but the version in bin is "2.0.0.0". To continue, remove files from the application's bin directory or remove the version specification in web.config."
once i have removed web.pages version line from config file and  try then also rename it to 2.0.0 but it not working.i am using vs 2010.